# Not all of navigation buttons work JQ Mobile

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Here is my

### code

i.e index.html https://jsbin.com/milafep/edit?html,output .

### Overview

I have in the panel ('Open Panel') a menu with features(6 links) the issue is that pages, *accurately* **navigation buttons** with from id #one to #four work but #five and #six doesn't. Buttons with `<a>` tag. I use PhoneGap Build version 1. Sorry for Polish content. I'm not using `data-ajax="false"` in linking.

### Question

Why?

### Note

On jsbin it works but on device (Quantum 350 with Android 4.2.2) doesn't

### Recap

4 buttons work, 2 doesn't

I think that it is a [image: bug]

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you have one panel in each page `DIV`, and that all your panels have the same ID: `id="myPanel"`.

Ensure that all `id` attributes are unique on a your HTML document.

Also see the HTML specification section 7.5.2 "Element identifiers: the id and class attributes": https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

```
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> <!-- NB: ID must be unique-->
    <a href="#one" class="ui-btn">Autor</a><br>
    <a href="#two" class="ui-btn">Biorytm</a><br>
    <a href="#three" class="ui-btn">Skaner</a><br>
    <a href="#four" class="ui-btn">Uczelnia</a><br>
    <a href="#five" class="ui-btn">Urządzenie</a><br>
    <a href="#six" class="ui-btn">Extra</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thx this is due to dumb automatic duplicating of pages (of course by me) I know about id and uniqueness but I didn't notice, it (answer) didn't help